# How to identify a page ending in a word document using python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

Need to identify when a page is ending in a word document and mark it with additional text like PAGEEND_<>.

I am able to iterate over paragraphs using the following code:

```
from docx.api import Document    
from docx.enum.text import WD_BREAK

inputfile = 'test.docx'
document = Document(inputfile)
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    # Write paragraph text into new document
    # Write additional text as PARAEND_<<ParaNumber>>
```

How do I do the same thing for every page?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that it's not possible to do reliably within `python-docx` because determining page boundaries is a function of the (runtime) page rendering engine and is not represented in the .docx file itself.

There are more details in the answer to this question:
[Page number python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193159/page-number-python-docx)

and this one:
[How to identify page breaks using python-docx from docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210216/how-to-identify-page-breaks-using-python-docx-from-docx)

Comment: thank you for your response. You are correct. We are not able to reliably extract the page endings. Still searching for possible approaches.

Comment: your answer at the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210216/how-to-identify-page-breaks-using-python-docx-from-docx mentions a method using version 2.7. Would you have a solution for python 3.0?