# Is there any solution to find the page breakpoint in python (for docx doccument)?

Tags: python, docx

[PLEASE REFER THE IMAGE FOR A BETTER UNDERSTANDNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxFww.jpg) I am developing an application which check the page break point of a DOCX file and if there is a page break point, then that page is ending at that point. I am literally fed up with many logics.
Hope i can get one.

Thanks and regards

Comment: could you please share some sample content of your DOCX file?

Comment: @nikn8 i have added the image please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

.DOCX files seem to do something called a soft breakpoint between pages.

However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210216/how-to-identify-page-breaks-using-python-docx-from-docx) seems to say that you can use `from docx import nsprefixes` to replace occurrences of page breaks with something more identifiable.

Comment: Actually i want to find where the page ends(i mean Page break point) using python.